# Associating values in list with integers in Python

Tags: python, list, function, loops, blackjack

I am working on a simple Blackjack game.

```
deck = ['Ace',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'Jack','Queen','King']

card_1 = random.choice(deck)
card_2 = random.choice(deck)

def my_hand(card_1,card_2):
    total = card_1 + card_2
    if total > 21:
        return "Bust!"
    elif total == 21:
        return "Blackjack!"
    elif total < 21:
        return "Hit again?"

print card_1,'and',card_2 
my_hand(card_1,card_2)
```

How do I assign specific items in the list an integer value?  Namely, I'd like to assign 'Ace' to the integer 1 or 11, and 'Jack', 'King', and 'Queen' equal to 10.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not clear on what you desire. Do you want to update the `deck` list? OR do you want to map `'Ace'` with 1 or 11 in another data-structure?

Comment: Why start with names like "Ace", etc., which are just for humans? Just use numbers to represent the cards throughout the whole program, and only translate them to words for output to humans.  Just because computer languages *can* use strings of letters doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary (and I suggest that you convert all keys to strings):

```
deck = {'Ace':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,
 'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
```

Comment: That will work, but is silly. Cards should be represented just as numbers, and only upon output to humans converted to names like "Ace".